# Reading 1000 line (350KB) XML file using Get-Content cmdlet takes 3minutes

Tags: powershell

I wrote a script which uses regex to check if certain pattern exist in file. 
The script reads the XML file line by line and checks if the pattern exists. If so, then it takes the line and adds it to the list. Afterwards it saves the list to another file.

The script does its job, but is super slow. It takes around 3 minutes just to read through only 1000 lines of XML file. I have check the script at two machines.

I have found out that `Get-Content` cmdlet is not much efficient for large files (50MB and more), but for small files like mine should be efficient enough.

Here is the code I wrote (Windows 10, Powershell v5.1):

```cs
$xmlFile = "C:\Dane\VSCrepo\Generator_Infa\impex\migrate\files_to_migrate\wf_TEST.xml"

$TemplateFile = "C:\Dane\VSCrepo\Generator_Infa\impex\migrate\ControlFile_temp.xml"
$OutputFile = "C:\Dane\VSCrepo\Generator_Infa\impex\migrate\ControlFile.xml"

$xmlText = Get-Content $xmlFile

# Read file
[String[]] $NewLines = @() 
foreach ($Line in $xmlText) {
    if ($Line -match '.*FOLDER *NAME ="\w+".*') {
        $FolderName = $Line -replace '.*FOLDER *NAME ="(\w+)".*', '$1'
        $NewLines += "<FOLDERMAP SOURCEFOLDERNAME=`"$FolderName`" SOURCEREPOSITORYNAME=`"REP_DEV`" TARGETFOLDERNAME=`"$FolderName`" TARGETREPOSITORYNAME=`"REP_TEST`"/>"
    }
}

$TemplateText = Get-Content $TemplateFile

# Write file
[String[]] $OutputText = @() 
foreach ($Line in $TemplateText) {
    $OutputText += $Line
    if ($Line -match ".*<IMPORTPARAMS CHECKIN.*") {
        #Add Lines after the selected pattern 
        $OutputText += $NewLines
    }
}
Set-Content $OutputFile $OutputText
```

Do you have any ideas if there is any easy method to improve performance of the code, without using .Net classes or another crazy things?

**UPDATE:**

XML file example:

```xml
<FOLDER NAME="XXXX" GROUP="" OWNER="idwbicc" SHARED="NOTSHARED" DESCRIPTION="" PERMISSIONS="rwx---r--" UUID="a33b65ea-7e70-4b3c-8dff-e6987d013fd2">
    <blah blah blah>
    <yeah yeah yeah>
    <SHORTCUT FOLDERNAME="AAA" FOO="BLAH" BAR="BLAH"/> 
    <.../>
</FOLDER>
<FOLDER NAME="YYYYY" GROUP="" OWNER="idwbicc" SHARED="NOTSHARED" DESCRIPTION="" PERMISSIONS="rwx---r--" UUID="a33b65ea-7e70-4b3c-8dff-e6987d013fd2">
    <blah blah blah>
    <yeah yeah yeah>
    <SHORTCUT FOLDERNAME="BBB" FOO="BLAH" BAR="BLAH"/> 
    <.../>
</FOLDER>
<FOLDER NAME="ZZZZ" GROUP="" OWNER="idwbicc" SHARED="NOTSHARED" DESCRIPTION="" PERMISSIONS="rwx---r--" UUID="a33b65ea-7e70-4b3c-8dff-e6987d013fd2">
    <blah blah blah>
    <yeah yeah yeah>
    <SHORTCUT FOLDERNAME="CCC" FOO="BLAH" BAR="BLAH"/> 
    <.../>
</FOLDER>
```

Regex match `-match '.*FOLDER *NAME ="\w+".*'` picks the lines:

```xml
<FOLDER NAME="XXXX" GROUP="" OWNER="idwbicc" SHARED="NOTSHARED" DESCRIPTION="" PERMISSIONS="rwx---r--" UUID="a33b65ea-7e70-4b3c-8dff-e6987d013fd2">
<SHORTCUT FOLDERNAME="AAA" FOO="BLAH" BAR="BLAH"/> 
<FOLDER NAME="YYYYY" GROUP="" OWNER="idwbicc" SHARED="NOTSHARED" DESCRIPTION="" PERMISSIONS="rwx---r--" UUID="a33b65ea-7e70-4b3c-8dff-e6987d013fd2">
<SHORTCUT FOLDERNAME="BBB" FOO="BLAH" BAR="BLAH"/> 
<FOLDER NAME="ZZZZ" GROUP="" OWNER="idwbicc" SHARED="NOTSHARED" DESCRIPTION="" PERMISSIONS="rwx---r--" UUID="a33b65ea-7e70-4b3c-8dff-e6987d013fd2">
<SHORTCUT FOLDERNAME="CCC" FOO="BLAH" BAR="BLAH"/>
```

Regex replacement `-replace '.*FOLDER *NAME ="(\w+)".*', '$1'` takes folder name from picked:

```
XXXX
AAA
YYYYY
BBB
ZZZZ
CCC
```

Each folder name is placed in:

```xml
<FOLDERMAP SOURCEFOLDERNAME="$FolderName" SOURCEREPOSITORYNAME="REP_DEV" TARGETFOLDERNAME="$FolderName" TARGETREPOSITORYNAME="REP_TEST"/>
```

List of the newly created lines is inserted in the output XML file.

Comment: The mediocre speed you are experiencing is do to the speed of the regexp.  Could you share with us the exaple data and what exactly you are trying to achive?

Comment: You may want to consider using `[System.IO.StreamReader]`. This doesn't put the whole file in to memory. [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @Ash Since the file is small, the amount of memory taken is not an issue.

Comment: Parsing XML line by line with a regular expression is a flawed approach. Scrap it and use a proper XML parser instead (`$xml = New-Object Xml; $xml.Load($xmlFile)`).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers agree! but for such small file and even my solution should be quick enough

Comment: Again, parsing XML line by line with a regular expression is a flawed approach (b/c it will break as soon as somebody changes the formatting of the input file). Whether or not it "should be quick enough" is irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you, I will use xml parser, as you said. But I still would like to know the reason why the script is so slow. If I would had to deal with log file or random text file I could not use xml parser.